# Azure Api App with Authentication and DB connection

Tags: api, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-apps

I'd like create Azue Api App backend for web and mobile clients.
In Visual Studio 2015, I created a Azure Api App Project, but I can't choose authentication (it's disable and default is No Authentication).
How can i add Individual User Account Auth and connect a DB with my api backend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should you not just create a regular ASP.net project with Web API and the Local Account authentication provided by .Net Identity?

Comment: When I create a Project in VS 2015, I can choose Local Account authentication provided by .Net Identity only for MVC prject. And It provides me APIs for registration and login. But I want just create a Web Api project that give me these functionality, with own DB.